# Which manual should i choose from list of manual on intel's site?

Tags: assembly, intel

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

the above link contains the list of manual provided by intel for assembly language programming. I am learning x86 assembly. Which one of them should i choose as reference for instruction set.

Please help me choose correct one.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation on Intel's site is probably going to be *far* too detailed for learning purposes. Reference documentation is designed for readers who are already familiar with the material, but just need to look something up now and then. For somebody new to the material, it's going to be completely incomprehensible (choosing which volume you need would be the least of your problems).

I would start with a Google search for [x86 tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=x86+tutorial) and pick something from there.

Answer (score 1):

The first, combined, [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Combined Volumes:1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 3A, 3B, and 3C](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf). It contains most of the stuff you'll need to know.

You could only choose volume 2, but it would be a too referencish reference. Volume 1 introduces things pretty well and you can actually read it. Volume 3 will answer system-related questions in detail.

I recommend the whole thing because you can find all the details in there. There're typos and omissions and double-checking the same thing in different chapters will help you figure out what exactly is meant.